# NSolid with Node 6

Tags: nsolid

I'm trying to get NSolid working with node 6, but NSolid 1.4 comes bundled with a node v4.4.7 interpreter. Is it possible to switch to Node 6 or is Node 6 not supported by NSolid?

Answer (score 4):

At this point, N|Solid doesn't support v6.x, as N|Solid is based on the LTS version, which is Node v4.X, but v6.x will turn into an LTS version in October 2016 and will be supported in N|Solid then.